# How to run Android's CTS on windows on an emulator

Tags: android, exception, classnotfoundexception

I downloaded **CTS tool** from  [this source](http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html)(Android 2.3 R3 CTS) and unzipped.
I have added **SDK_ROOT** in my environment variables and set path to android SDk directory.
I have set path to **"path=c:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools"** for ADB.
I used

```
 java -Xmx512M -cp c:\android-cts\tools\cts.jar;
 c:\android-cts\tools\hosttestlib.jar;
 c:\android-cts\tools\junit.jar;
 c:\android-cts\tools\CtsTestAnnotationsHostLib;
 c:\android-sdk-windows\tools\lib\ddmlib.jar"
```

to enter CTS shell.
**But it gives error..**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/ddmlib/An
droidDebugBridge$IDeviceChangeListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.cts.TestHost.<clinit>(TestHost.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBrid
ge$IDeviceChangeListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Could not find the main class: `com.android.cts.TestHost`.  Program will exit.

I am not able to get to `CTS Console screen`..please do help..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue by using cygwin

I found the solution on [this blog](http://yenliangl.blogspot.com/2011/05/run-android-cts.html)

You just have to do the modification of those two line in the script startcts :
JARS=`cygpath -w -p ${CTS_LIB}:${DDM_LIB}:${JUNIT_LIB}:${HOSTTEST_LIB}`
java ${JAVA_OPTS} -cp ${JARS} com.android.cts.TestHost `cygpath -w ${CONFIG}` "$@" ${DDCONFIG}

Then I was able to have the CTS prompt